# Как слинковать nettle и libasn?

Tags: linux, компиляция, линковка

Компилирую:

```
kali ~/httpsfs # cc  -g -O2  -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -fsanitize=undefined -fanalyzer -Wno-analyzer-file-leak -rdynamic -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DVERSION=\"1.2.3\" `pkg-config --cflags-only-I gumbo libcurl fuse uuid expat` `pkg-config --libs-only-L gumbo libcurl fuse uuid expat` -o httpdirfs main.o network.o fuse_local.o link.o cache.o util.o sonic.o log.o config.o memcache.o -pthread -lgumbo -lcurl -lfuse -lexpat -luuid -lcrypto -lssl -lldap -lgnutls -static -lnettle -ldl
undefined reference to asn...
undefined reference to nettle...
```

```
 ~ # apt list | grep nettle

libnettle6/bionic,now 3.4-1 arm64 [installed]
libnettle8/unknown,unstable,kali-rolling,now 3.7.3-1 arm64 [installed]
nettle-bin/unknown,unstable,kali-rolling,now 3.7.3-1 arm64 [installed]
nettle-dev/unknown,unstable,kali-rolling,now 3.7.3-1 arm64 [installed,automatic]

 ~ # apt list | grep libasn
libasn1-8-heimdal/unknown,unstable,kali-rolling,now 7.7.0+dfsg-3+b1 arm64 [installed,automatic]
libasn1-8-heimdal/bionic 7.5.0+dfsg-1 armhf
libasn1-combinators-ocaml-dev/unknown,unstable,kali-rolling,now 0.2.6-2+b5 arm64 [installed]
libasn1-combinators-ocaml/unknown,unstable,kali-rolling,now 0.2.6-2+b5 arm64 [installed,automatic]
osmo-libasn1c-dev/unknown,unstable,kali-rolling,now 0.9.33-1 arm64 [installed]
osmo-libasn1c-dev/bionic 0.9.28-2 armhf
osmo-libasn1c0/bionic 0.9.28-2 arm64
osmo-libasn1c0/bionic 0.9.28-2 armhf
osmo-libasn1c1/unknown,unstable,kali-rolling,now 0.9.33-1 arm64 [installed,automatic]
```

Да я явно указываю -lasn1c, -lnettle, а их не видит, хотя библиотеки на месте! Что делать???

Comment: Вы указали флаг -static, значит линковки происходит с *.a библиотеками. Докажите их наличие в путях командой ls.

Comment: Можно поискать в каких пакетах статические библиотеки командой apt-file search...

Comment: есть /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libnettle.a и /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libasn1c.a (хост - Kali Nethunter)

Comment: Если явно добавить флаг - L/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu ?